# How to redirect page on MSAL Azure B2C Clojurescript?

Tags: azure, clojurescript, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated Azure AD B2C on my web app, built using `Clojurescript` and the MSAL library.

Now we are showing popups for our user flows. But instead of a popup we want to redirect to a different page.

How can we redirect to a new page with this setup?

Comment: Have you tried `loginRedirect` instead of the `loginPopup` while logging in using MSAL.?

Comment: Did it resolve your issue by using `loginRedirect` or still looking for any help

Answer (score 0):

In MSAL you can sign in the users in two ways

1. Pop-up window which uses `loginPopup` method
2. Redirect uses `loginRedirect` method

By using the `loginRedirect` method you can redirect to a new page with out poping up new window.

> myMsal.loginRedirect(loginRequest);

Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#sign-in-with-redirect) for more information